# Php custom header information cannot read over html form

Tags: php, authentication, header

I've some error for my php codes. If I request for then I cannot read Authorization header information. But I see response header Authorization information on Chrome Developer / Network section. Meanwhile.. I can not see response.php / request header information about .

Request.php :

```
$authToken = '123123123';
header('Authorization:'.$authToken.'');
header('Connection: close');
header('Location: http://domain.com/bank_test/index.php?apikey=123123123');
```

Response.php :

```
echo $_SERVER['Authorization'];
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .? - [E=Authorization:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing there is you're sending HTTP **Response** headers to the client. An `Authorization` header in a **response** doesn't really do anything. One of your headers, the `Location` header, is instructing the client to make a new request to a different URL. It will do so, **but it will not use any of the headers you sent in the response.**

In other words, you cannot dictate to the client what request headers to send after a `Location` redirect.

If you want to be in more control of request headers a client sends, the only way to do that is to make an AJAX request from Javascript on the client side. However, that is not the same as redirecting the client to a different URL and is probably also not what you want.

Comment: if I'm using curl with json. it's ok. it is my first opnion for api users.

Well.. I tried to html-form process. I did not get again Authorization value.